# Give one sound the characteristics of another

Tags: plug-ins, pro-tools, post-production

Hi, 
I swear I used to have a plug in which did this, but as many of you, the sea of tools at my hands has quickly caused my memory to drown.

I'm basically looking to take around 30 tonal sounds, and apply the waveform characteristics of another 30 tonal sounds to it. Such as to alter the envelope / decay etc.  Something like vocalign I guess, but I'm sure there was something else.

As usual any help is greatly appreciated. : )

Answer (score 6):

To be clear, do you mean the "envelope / decay" ie the volume OR do you mean the tonal/spectrum?

The first requires an envelope follower, which cam be done manually (i.e. trace the waveform of the source sound by creating via manually drawing a volume graph that tracks/traces its level/waveform & then cut/remove it from that track and paste it in the same sync position on the destination track) and maybe automatically with some tweaking & setup (the bluecat analysis/metering plugins can output MIDI of any chosen parameter, so eg output MIDI of volume, send it to control the fader of the destination track) - I did this the manual way on the film Bridge to Terabithia for some creature vocals, using the pitched vocal track from a giant tree and pasting the volume/envelope grpah on to a track of roughly synced branch/leaf shakes....

http://www.bluecataudio.com/Products/Category_Analysis/

The second requires cross synthesis - convolution does this to a degree, AudioSculpt does this with more control, have a read of the AudioSculpt cross synthesis manual/handbook:

http://homepages.gold.ac.uk/ems/pdf/AS-Cross%20Synthesis%20Handbook.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Max/MSP's Convolution is alright and also SoundHack has some awesome Mutation and convolution processes.

Comment: I was going to suggest SoundHack as well: Classic, powerful, and free. Worth downloading for it Convolution alone. 

Answer (score 1):

one option is to use a vocoder (like Waves Morphoder) to use one sound as the carrier, and another as the modulator.